# Spawning cmd shell in java makes cmd.exe have open handle to java directory

Tags: java, windows, cmd, handle

I have a Java application that I am pushing an update to the bundled JRE. Doing this makes me restart the app because obviously it cannot be running while the JRE is being replaced. I open cmd and rename the old folder and then rename the new folder - this way, if renaming fails, the app will boot the old version still. I don't have the resources to make a more full fledged update mechanism, and I don't really have interest in spending time developing something for this.

I am having an issue though where there is still an open handle from the spawned cmd process to the java/lib/modules directory. As such, it cannot be renamed and it always fails.

[image]

I cannot figure out why this handle is open. The code I use to run this update script is

```
public void runUpdateScript() {
    String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "start", "cmd.exe", "/c", ModManager.getTempDir() + "updater.cmd"};
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        pb.directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
        pb.start();
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handler code goes here. Not necessary for this SO post
    }
}
```

My script waits for 4 seconds which I have checked is well more than enough time for java.exe to end. But somehow there is this open file handle, and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: This is a regression introduced in Java 9.  See linked Q&A for details and possible workarounds.

Comment: The batch script could use [handle.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) to find and close the handle for the directory handle. The following snippet is a start that iterates over the file and section handles in a process and parses out the handle, type, and path: `for /f "skip=4 tokens=1-3* delims=: " %%a in ('handle.exe -p %pid%') do @(echo "handle=%%a, type=%%b, path=%%d")`. If the type (`%%b`) is "File" and the path (`%%d`) matches the Java directory, you can close the handle with `handle -p %pid% -c %%a -y`.

Comment: You can get the cmd.exe PIDs from tasklist, e.g. `for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist -nh -fo csv /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe"') do @echo name=%%~a, pid=%%~b`

Comment: Thanks everyone, I still have ability to update program, so I can work around the JRE updater issue.